# Removing Podcasts Documents and Data

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, storage, podcasts.app

I've had issues with the stock iOS podcast app for a while now- syncing was broken, it kept crashing while downloading, etc etc. I decided to move to Downcast. Anyways, after deleting all my podcast subscriptions, and then telling iTunes not to sync any podcasts to the device, I still have **3.3 GB of "documents and data" from the Podcasts app.**

Obviously, I'd like to clear that space up. The Podcast app still will not open for me (white screen to crash every time), but there shouldn't be any Podcasts to delete in there anyways. Without being able to delete a stock app, is there any way for me to remove this waste of storage space?

Would prefer not to wipe the phone. iPhone 5, iOS 8.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [forum post on Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30643334#message30643334) points out that on iOS 10 it is possible to reduce the Podcasts app’s “Documents & Data” by temporarily removing the app:

> Good news for everyone that has been dealing with this issue - iOS 10 has a new feature that help resolve the Podcasts storage problem.
>
> One thing you can now do in iOS 10 is 'delete' stock apps from your device. It doesn't really delete the app, but it deletes the icon link from the apps and it also *removes associated data and configuration files!*  This means that deleting the Podcasts app will also delete the huge data file.
>
> Once removed, the Podcasts app can just be readded from the App Store, and the settings are instantly restored from your iCloud account.
>
> [image: Screenshot Podcasts App Storage Before] [image: Screenshot Deleting Podcasts App] [image: Screenshot Podcasts App Storage After]

( I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it while trying to find out why the Podcasts app is using a few hundred megabytes worth of “Documents & Data” on my iPhone in addition to the storage it uses for downloaded podcast episodes, and I thought it was still worth providing an updated answer pointing out that on iOS 10 this can be more easily fixed. I haven’t been able to try this myself yet, as I am still on iOS 9. )

ONE THING TO NOTE:
Any podcasts you have downloaded, but are not subscribed to will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage; tap on Podcasts, then you can swipe each podcast to delete it. If it doesn't show up there, then the data is borked, and you'll need to restore the device.

Comment: It wound up being something that could only be fixed by a device restore. There were no podcasts visible in the storage menu, but 3.3 GB of "documents and data."